# Time zone disappears in output in R system time

Tags: r, date, time

I am trying to output the system date and time to a text file. When I do so, the time zone disappears. An example follows:

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2012-05-24 09:58:38 CDT"
> currentTime <- Sys.time()
> currentTime
[1] "2012-05-24 09:58:49 CDT"
> cat(as.character(currentTime), sep = "\n")
2012-05-24 09:58:49
```

What happened to the time zone and how to I get it back?

Comment: Why are you converting to `as.character`? This causes your problem.

Comment: @Andrie If they don't, doesn't it just print the number of seconds?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
cat(format(Sys.time(),usetz = TRUE))
```

The print method for POSIXct objects calls `format` with `usetz = TRUE` which is why you see the time zone in the console (the print method is called behind the scenes).